# Waitfor doesn't recognize the expression in Perl

Tags: perl

I've a waitfor command, but its not recognizing the pattern. What may be wrong?

```
while(@wait = $t->waitfor('/bash-3.2\$ $/i'))
```

Thanks,
Sharath

Comment: What class does the object `$t` come from?

Comment: Regex could be more general.

Comment: What is your $PS1 set to on the target machine?

Comment: echo $PS1 gives an output of "\s-\v\$".
$t is defined as $t = new Net::Telnet (Timeout => undef,Errmode=>'return');

Comment: I need bash shell to execute some commmands. Hence i type "bash" after login in.

Comment: You should just edit /etc/passwd and change your login shell if you want bash.

Comment: I'm executing "bash" command before this command. So it should already be in bash shell.

Comment: @choroba: My crystal ball says it's probably a [Net::Telnet](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net::Telnet) object.  It would be nice if the OP could confirm that, though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `waitfor` to match your PS1 prompt.

On my machine if I:

```
export PS1=export PS1="\s-\v\$"
```

my prompt becomes:

```
bash-3.2$
```

So I think your code should be looking for

```
while(@wait = $t->waitfor('/bash\-3\.2\$/i'))
```

Which hopefully matches

I have to wonder though if your regex is the problem.

If you run an interactive command such as bash it will never return control to the program as it has no user input.  Also, the while loop scares me a bit.  I'm not sure why you need that.

If you really need bash try running your commands with `bash -c <some command>`
That way bash will run your single command and return the result.

Comment: My bash prompt comes as "bash-3.2$". I tried your code but its not working :(

Comment: Can we add regualr expressions so as to check for spaces and numbers, like waitfor('[spaces]bash[numbers] $/i'). How do i do this?

Comment: So figure it out.  You just have to find a matching [regex](http://regex101.com/r/xN3aR4).  I can't possibly know what your program is doing.

Comment: hmm :( well that is what i'm finding it difficult